# Effect of Increment of Variable on Output in a Multivariate Equation

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

There is an equation as you can see below. Here, C1, C2 and C3 denote constants, while x and y denote variables.

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCbnf.png)

I want to observe the effect of x on U. In short, will increasing x increase or decrease U? **How can I prove this mathematically?** I tried using *limit* but it didn't work because of two different variables. In addition, a constraint such as 40<x<55 can be set for x.